# Retrieving dll path of a running process

Tags: scripting, powershell, batch-file

I have an application that uses a .dll file, there are 2 different locations for the file and I need to find out which one it is using on over 200 machines.

I am very new to power shell and have tried Get-Process method but it does not supply the information I need, is there another way to retrieve this in power shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [article](http://trevorsullivan.net/2010/08/25/powershell-finding-currently-loaded-dlls/) gives one approach using a WMI provider call. You could use the provided Function at the end. If your just looking for something quick and dirty this would work.

Digging in a little more, This might be what you want:

```
$modules = Get-Process | Where { $_.ProcessName -eq "process.name" } | Select Modules
$modules.Modules
```

Replace process.name with your process name

Comment: This is not outputting anything, I did exact same thing as you did up here but changed my process name

Comment: Noticed a typo in the code. Is your process a standard process? Did you use the name as it is displayed when you just run Get-Process?

Comment: Remove the FileName from the second command, not sure how that got on there.

Comment: As an example lets use Chrome. I want to know the exact dll's that it is using including file paths of those dlls without using any third party applications. With the above code I finally caught the type (SMH) and it comes back with all Chrome processes but not file path

Comment: $modules = Get-Process | Where { $_.ProcessName -eq "chrome" } | Select Modules will return me a list of the "chrome" (notice it is case sensitive) processes running on my machine. Because I have more than one "chrome" instance, I need to do $modules[0].Modules to get the list. See @Rynant's answer to do this in one command.

Answer (score 3):

The DLLs for a process are contained in the Modules property of the Process object returned by `Get-Process`.

```
Get-Process notepad| select -ExpandProperty modules| Format-Table -AutoSize
```

To look for a specific DLL, you could do something like this:

```
Get-Process chrome| 
    select -ExpandProperty modules|
    foreach { if($_.ModuleName -eq 'pdf.dll'){$_.Filename} }
```

Since there could be many processes with the same name, you could use this to show only the distinct DLL locations:

```
Get-Process chrome| 
    select -ExpandProperty modules|
    where {$_.ModuleName -eq 'pdf.dll'}|
    group -Property FileName|
    select name
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article a while back on how to find DLLs that were loaded by a particular process. You can probably adapt this code to find your specific DLL.

http://trevorsullivan.net/2010/08/25/powershell-finding-currently-loaded-dlls/